Movie/TV where guys eyes hurt, tear, and burn like crazy while proposing his love to a woman
I'm looking for a movie or possibly a TV show with the following scene in it:
One guy gives another guy a little flask with a clear liquid in it and tells him to apply a few drops underneath his eyes so that he cries a little. But he applies to much and while proposing his feelings to a woman (I think) he cries like crazy and also his eyes burn like hell so he can't finish what he was saying.
I'm certain it's an American movie and I guess it's comedy like Party Animals.

Isn't there a scene in Pearl Harbor (2001, starring Ben Affleck, Josh Hartnett, and Kate Beckinsale) like this? I don't remember for sure so I don't want to add it as an answer. The new pilots are at a club flirting with the nurses. One pilot gives another pilot some kind of liquid to put under his eyes. He is supposed to tell her that he could die at any day and use the liquid to cry. But it just confuses her and she asks him whats wrong with his eyes. But this is before war is declared so I don't know why they would think they could die at any time... Does this sound right?

Oh my god... you're right! Thank you! This was bugging me for two days. I was so off with my assumption. Before comedy I thought it was a drama and something about drugs and the two guys wore business suits.
Anyway my mind is at easy now. Thanks again!

Great! I haven't seen that movie probably since it came out. Glad I remembered it correctly. I've added my comment as an answer.

This sounds like a scene from the 2001 movie Pearl Harbor, starring Ben Affleck, Josh Hartnett, and Kate Beckinsale.
There is a scene where the new pilots are at a club bar trying to pick up the nurses. One pilot gives another pilot some kind of liquid to put under his eyes. The idea is that he will tell her that he might die any day, and the liquid will irritate his eyes, to make it look like he is crying.
He ends up crying too much, and the nurse is just confused. She asks him what is wrong with his eyes.
